# Parallel async tasks emitted by endless generator

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a code that very close to this:

```
class Parser:
    async def fetch(self, url):
        html = await get(url)
        return html

    @property
    def endless_generator(self):
        while True:
            yield url

    async def loop():
        htmls = []
        for url in self.endless_generator:
            htmls.append(await self.fetch(url))
        return htmls

    def run(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        try:
            htmls = loop.run_until_complete(self.loop())
        finally:
            loop.close()

parser = Parser()
parser.run()
```

Now `Parser.loop` run synchronously.

I've tried `asyncio.wait` and `asyncio.gather` to achieve async invocations of `Parser.fetch`, but I don't know the number of URLs in advance (because URLs yielding by endless generator).

So, how do I get asynchronous calls if the number of tasks is not known in advance?

Answer (score 2):

> I've tried `asyncio.wait` and `asyncio.gather` to achieve async invocations of `Parser.fetch`, but I don't know the number of URLs in advance (because URLs yielding by endless generator).

I assume that by endless generator you mean a generator whose number of URLs is not known in advance, rather than a truly endless generator (generating an infinite list). Here is a version that creates a task as soon as a URL is available, and gathers the results as they arrive:

```
async def loop():
    lp = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = set()
    result = {}
    any_done = asyncio.Event()

    def _task_done(t):
        tasks.remove(t)
        any_done.set()
        result[t.fetch_url] = t.result()

    for url in self.endless_generator:
        new_task = lp.create_task(self.fetch(url))
        new_task.fetch_url = url
        tasks.add(new_task)
        new_task.add_done_callback(_task_done)
        await any_done.wait()
        any_done.clear()

    while tasks:
        await any_done.wait()
        any_done.clear()

    return result  # mapping url -> html
```

One cannot simply call `gather` or `wait` in each iteration because that would wait for all the existing tasks to finish before queuing a new one. `wait(return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)` could work, but it would be `O(n**2)` in the number of tasks because it would set up its own callback each time anew.

Comment: `tasks = [self.fetch(url) for url in self.endless_generator]` produces a list in a memory. Firstly, it's inefficient in my case (number of URLs can be huge). Secondary, `self.endless_generator` yielding URLs `while some_flag is True`, whose state I changing inside another method, so generator is "approximately endless".

Comment: @0x1337 I've now edited the answer to do what I think you're asking for, but I'm still not 100% sure. Perhaps `endless_generator` should really be an async generator for the whole thing to work.

Comment: What does  `new_task.fetch_url`?

Comment: @0x1337 The assignment was missing, sorry about that. It associates the task with the url, which enables the function to return a meaningful value.